# Can't upgrade from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 - Package magento could not be found in any version

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to upgrade via command line from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 but I keep getting errors.

Here is what I did first:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1 --no-update
composer update
```

Then I've got the error below (The requested package magento could not be found in any version), see image:
[image]

I have tried using (product-community-edition 2.1 , product-community-edition 2.1.0 , product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc3) and nothing.

I tried to change the composer repo by using:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer repo.magento.com
```

Then I run again the commands to update and now I have a different error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
```

`Your configuration does not allow connections to http://repo.magento.com/packages.json. See https://getco`

Any help is appreciated.

---

### Update - Posting Compose File

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.0.2",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "repo.magento.com"
    }
},
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento": "2.0.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
```

Comment: can you post your composer.json file?

Comment: Done. I have edited the post.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the part `"magento": "2.0.1"` as `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1",` will already take care of the Magento installation.

Otherwise try to reinstall Magento based on the Documentation.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce

Comment: Ok. It didn't work, however, you opened my eyes to changing two other things, first I rewrite line on the top ""version": "2.0.2"," to my current one ""version": "2.0.7"," then I changed " "url": "repo.magento.com"" including https and worked 100%. =D

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your original post:

- `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>` will work. You don't need `2.1.0` because it's the latest version (notice `project` instead of `product`)
- The version has three numbers, so if you use it, use `2.1.0` instead of `2.1`